# BIND9 + PROXY настройка

Tags: dns

Добрый день дорогие друзья, появился вопрос по DNS proxy resolve. 
Имеется BIND9 который переводят все запросы на 1 ip адресс который является прокси серверов на privoxy. 
Задача такова - Кода пользователь запрашивает сайт он получает ip прокси сервера , и пре запросе на прокси сервер получает контент сайта который запрашивал именно от ip proxy. В google не нашел решения .. Был бы рад если бы кто нибудь подсказал , как решить данную проблему.

Заранее спасибо огромное.

Comment: А не проще ли у клиента в браузере прокси указать?

Comment: нет , так как больше 2000 ПК

Comment: То, что Вы хотите, никто не делает. В таком случае используют прозрачное проксирование.

Comment: ... но если очень хочется, попробуйте включить `accept-intercepted-requests`. Может, заработает.

Comment: Не заработало . ((

Comment: @AlexMixayelovichSokolov А зачем вы вообще с помощью bind меняете ip адреса. Пусть остаются как есть. Трафик перехватываете iptables например, заворачивая полностью 80й порт на свою проксю. Правда сейчас больше половины интернета уже на 443 по SSL идут. Можно и 443 завернуть, но тогда надо будет сертификаты на лету генерить подписывая неким сертфикатом, которому доверяют ваши клиенты